# How can I write a loop which understand a thread has finished and starts new thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to write a thread which  understand a thread has finished and starts new thread.
I mean I wrote this code :

```
 new Thread(new Runnable(){ 
            @Override public void run(){
    //code here
                } 
           }).start();
```

But I want to do it in for loop.
I want to create just 5 thread.But when a thread has finished I want to create a new one.

```
for(int i=0;i<300;i++)
{
 //I want to create 5 thread here and stop code  and then when a thread has finished I want //to create  new thread.
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to implement a Thread Pool?

Comment: thanks for replying. actually I dont know what it means. But I want to create 5 thread for i=0,1,2,3,4,5 and then I want to wait when thread count is less then 5 I want to create a new thread.

Comment: 'when a thread has finished I want to create a new one' - what is wrong with the old one?  If you want to 'start a thread again', just put a loop in the old thread.

Comment: @MartinJames I mean it finished its work. I give new task to thread.

Comment: Producer-consumer queue and a while loop in each thread.

Comment: @MartinJames it doenst matter , just I dont want to run 6 threads at the same time. I want from i=0 to 300 always 5 threads works

Comment: So why use threads? Why not just run your computations sequentially without the overhead of creating, starting, and waiting for threads at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a more universal method, but more low level you can use a **semaphore**:

```
final Semaphore s = new Semaphore(5);
for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
{
    final int j = i;

    s.acquire();

    new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                System.out.println("Thread " + j + " starts.");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println("Thread " + j + " ends.");
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally
            {
                s.release();
            }
        }

    }).start();
}
```

Comment: Semaphore means 5 threads run at the same time? or one thread waits the others?

Comment: A semaphore limits the number of times it can be acquired: so here the semaphore can be acquired 5 times, any attempt to acquire it one more time will block until one of the threads release it.

Comment: To be pedantic: **at most** 5 threads run at the same time. Because first between the moment a thread release the semaphore and another is launched there is a (likely ridiculously small) delay. Secondly at the end, when all the first 296 ends there is still 4 running, then 3 running...

Comment: I have just one question. Semaphore works which I want. But I want to wonder about semaphore or threadpool is faster? Thank you

Answer (score 5):

The thread class has these methods, which could be used to do what you want:

```
Thread.join()
Thread.isAlive()
```

But, you probably really want to use a thread pool, like this:

```
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++) {
        executor.submit(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I want to use variable i in run method but I cant. Because it need to be declared as a final but it doesnt allow too

Comment: @user2328779: you can't mark it `final` because you change it with `i++`. Just use a temporary variable `j` in your loop like in my sample.

Comment: @Pragmateek I cant because it says annot assign a value to final variable sayac_thread

Comment: If you are planning to modify the variable in multiple threads you are going to run into a new problem-- writing to the same variable in multiple threads is not thread safe.  If appropriate, consider having the threads operate on an java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger

Comment: @user2328779: why would you want to change `i`? If you don't need, my code implements a "standard" way of reading it from your runnable.

Comment: @Pragmateek I want to use variable `i` because depends on `i` I make thread some works. Think in thread I want to write like array[i]

Comment: @user2328779: then you can use my temporary tricks if you only need to read `i`, just try it. :)

Comment: @Keith thread pool means for 5 threads , always max 5 threads work to finish the work.If a thread finish his work new one starts right?

Answer (score 0):

You sounded like you want to create task base on the currently running task. Here I have an example which you could create new task in another task. Perhaps, you may also want to look at `java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool`

```
final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

executorService.submit(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //code here which run by 5 threads, thread can be reused when the task is finished

        //new task can be created at the end of another task
        executorService.submit(...)
    }
});
```